# What is the recommending interface to a utility that requires many parameters?

Tags: command-line, arguments

I'm building a command-line utility that requires six pieces of information to work correctly. It looks like this:

```
fm-git filename repository path comment username password
```

However, on any individual system, `username` and `password` will be constant.

When executing the utility, I'm finding it difficult to build. For example, here's one test call to the utility (broken into multiple lines for readability):

```
/Users/chuck/Projects/fm-git/fm-git.py chiv-lib
/Users/chuck/Projects/chiv-lib/ Chivalry/ "continued testing"
Administrator abc1234
```

I'm considering different ways to pass these arguments. For example, `fm-git -f filename -r repository ...` or `fm-git --filename filename --repository repository...`. I'm also considering making the `username` and `password` arguments configuration settings, since they generally won't change, and they could then be eliminated from the utility call.

When utility arguments are many but required, what is the accepted practice for maintaining utility call readability?

Comment: I think having required flags like '--non-optional` value is useful if you have a lot of arguments. Because remembering positions is hard. It's worth noting that command line arguments are visible to other users, so passing passwords through them is considered bad form - in case you weren't aware of the fact. I personally *hate* having to create configuration files to use a tool, though like being able to. You might like to follow how `git` works for configuration settings

Comment: @AttRigh Re: passwords: I agree, but when the utility is finished, it will probably never be called by a user, but automatically, the call being built by another program, so I'm not too worried about security, especially since the credentials are for a program on the same machine as the utility is being run on. But I'll look into `git` configuration and see if it's applicable.

Comment: @Chuck Arguments are visible no matter how the program is run. Be it by the user interactively or by a script, it is visible. So if you are passing passwords as an argument, you effectively don't have them

Comment: @Chuck I'd focus on making the script easy to call, from the caller's perspective. `--option value` is nice because it keeps people from having to remember the right order, and allows a script to build the command in any order. It is also extensible

Comment: password probably shouldn't be in the CLI as that's totally snoopable and may be logged in all sorts of places; put those in a file and read it (passwords in environment variables get sent to any child processes by default, which may or may not be a problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's good idea to:

1. calculate dependent arguments but allow to redefine them: for example in your example you have `filename` the same as `$(basename repository)`, so you may require only repository, but have option `--filename` to provide alternative filename.
2. hide auth from command line and `ps` output. Put them in some file: may be `$HOME/.fm-git.conf`, give file more restrictions like `chmod 600 $HOME/.fm-git.conf` and read them from file. Somtimes it is also an option to get username and password from environment variables (like default username is your system username or `SUDO_USER`) but may be it's not your case.

So after that two optimisations you have only 3 cli parameters, it's acceptable I think. Feel free to either use them as positional parameter or provide some flags like `--comment`: providing long flags will enhance readability if you use your program in scripts further, but will require to type more if you will run your program mostly by hands from cli.

Anyway, as you write your program in Python, I recommend you to use [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) -- it will help you parse parameters and make changes in future if you'd like to change them.

Comment: I moved the credentials to a configuration file in the user's home folder, `.fm-git`, and the rest of the arguments now use option names and `argparse`.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, unix applications allow for multiple ways to provide this information, with the more "specific" ways overriding the less specific ones.

So you have:

- For graphical applications, the toolkit used nearly always provides some way to have resource (e.g. `xrdb`-style in plain X, etc.)
- a configuration file, if the toolkit doesn't already provide one.
- commandline options, both short form and long form (easy with `getopt` in C)
- reasonable defaults if no information is given, e.g. the current directory for a path

Positional parameters only make sense for a few mandatory ones, followed possibly by a list of files (because wildcard specifications expand to multiple parameters). Six individual pieces are too many; the order is difficult to remember, so use options for these.

For passwords, it can be helpful to provide a way to make the application read the password from stdin, possibly by using a special value (e.g. `--password -` or `-p -`).

The whoever uses the application can choose if hardcoded passwords, passwords in configuration files, or letting the user input the password is the best option for the particular use-case.